# Preventing page from going back to parent page after clicking on pop up Ok button in classic asp

Tags: page-refresh

i have written following code for pop up :

```
function OpenApproveLevelPopup() {
   // debugger;
    //document.frmopportunity.txtopplvl.value = 'Level2';
    var url = 'ApprovePopUp_shilpa.asp?opprApprLvl=' + document.frmopportunity.txtopplvl.value;
     //+ document.frmopportunity.txtopplvl.value;
    var windowRetVal = window.showModalDialog(url, "", "dialogHeight:150px;dialogWidth:280px;status: No;");
    document.frmopportunity.txtopplvl.value = windowRetVal;
    //TheForm.
    return windowRetVal;
}
```

and i am calling this function on click of a button using following code:

```
<TD><INPUT class=standard type=submit value='Change Opportunity Design Level' name=ChangeOpportunityDesignLevel onclick = ' return OpenApproveLevelPopup()' ></TD></TR>"
```

After clicking on OK button in pop up ,my page is getting refreshed and it is going back to Parent page,i dnt want this.Please help me reatining the same even after clicking on OK button.